# Is Gmail removing "Received" in headers?

Tags: gmail, pop3

I added my professional email to my gmail account as POP3 and set it as default for sending emails. Strangely, when sending emails to other emails like hotmail, or even by using tools like mail-tester or mailgenius, for each of them I see in headers something like that :

**Gmail to Hotmail**

```
Received: from server1 by server2 with esmtps
Received: from google-server by server2
Received: by google-server
```

But somehow, when I send an email to another gmail account, the first "Received" is different...

**Gmail to Gmail**

```
Received: from server2 by server2 with LMTP id wGSgNXg5bGIpwQEAIcWi0g
Received: from google-server by server2
Received: by google-server
```

Notice esmtps was replaced by LMTP with some ID, and server1 is not there anymore.

How is this possible and how can I fix this? I need that server1 for SPF check.

**More detailed - Gmail to Hotmail**

```
Received: from nwpro1.fcomet.com ([172.104.22.223])
    by mx36.antispamcloud.com with esmtps (TLSv1.3:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:256)
    (Exim 4.92)
    (envelope-from <professional@domain.com>)
    id 1nk4co-0007F6-CK
    for private@hotmail.com; Thu, 28 Apr 2022 15:56:08 +0200
Received: from mail-vs1-f52.google.com ([209.85.217.52]:42929)
    by nwpro1.fcomet.com with esmtpsa  (TLS1.3) tls TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    (Exim 4.94.2)
    (envelope-from <professional@domain.com>)
    id 1nk4c9-00BNxm-QH
    for private@hotmail.com; Thu, 28 Apr 2022 09:55:23 -0400
Received: by mail-vs1-f52.google.com with SMTP id i186so4660856vsc.9
    for <private@hotmail.com>; Thu, 28 Apr 2022 06:55:23 -0700 (PDT)
```

**More detailed - Gmail to Gmail**

```
Received: from nwpro1.fcomet.com 
    by nwpro1.fcomet.com with LMTP id wGSgNXg5bGIpwQEAIcWi0g 
    (envelope-from <professional_first@domain.com>) 
    for <professional_second@domain.com>; Fri, 29 Apr 2022 15:16:08 -0400
Received: from mail-ed1-f52.google.com ([209.85.208.52]:37606) 
    by nwpro1.fcomet.com with esmtpsa (TLS1.3) tls TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    (Exim 4.94.2)
    (envelope-from <professional_first@domain.com>) id 1nkW67-000XKe-6M 
    for professional_second@domain.com; Fri, 29 Apr 2022 15:16:08 -0400
Received: by mail-ed1-f52.google.com with SMTP id k27so10117156edk.4
    for <professional_second@domain.com>; Fri, 29 Apr 2022 12:16:08 -0700 (PDT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The esmtps is a secure version of the extended smtp protocol, the LMTP protocol you're seeing in the second request is because that request is more local (e.g., from the same server).

You probably wouldn't ever see that esmtps if its not even leaving the host.

Some more information about the situation may help, ie, sending from hotmail to gmail got this or from gmail to gmail got this.
:)

I appreciate the edit to the question, but I am not sure if that helps.
The sources haven't really changed, and I am not sure that this is the true header.

```
All the headers I found are like this:
Received: by filterdrecv-75d94df84d-wmwh2 with SMTP id filterdrecv-75d94df84d-wmwh2-1-626C6700-1A
        2022-04-29 22:30:24.062932892 +0000 UTC m=+1989919.691835974
Received: from MjIyOTcyNTI (unknown)
```

Sources:

```
ESMTP (minus s, as that is ssl)
https://help.returnpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/220564347-What-is-Extended-Simple-Mail-Transfer-Protocol-ESMTP-
SMTP
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol
LMTP
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Mail_Transfer_Protocol
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation for the 2 protocoles. I edited the question for a better comprehension of the problem!

Comment: The sources haven't really changed, but the source I need (antispamcloud) just vanished.. It was replaced by the other source... Does LMTP does this? The only thing I changed from the header (beside removing what isn't part of "Received") is the email. Everything else is as it is in the headers I'm seeing.

Comment: Where is your DNS hosted? Google likes to bypass some lookups in favour of their own. The antispam header may be getting bypassed rather than removed.

Sorry walked away to supper. :-)

Comment: Hmmm, on further reading (I'm not at my main comp) the sent server is the same but the middle referrer is different,  I think because Google knows it's not sending to a different location, it was able to skip the middle man.

Comment: Have you tried sending from that pop account in Gmail to another service, ie proton mail or something? And looking at the referrers?

Comment: LMTP just means that google know it's sending to google and said, why leave the house, we can deliver this to ourselves. :-)

Comment: DNS is hosted on "fast comet". After testing, it seems that sending from gmail to fast comet (before bringing into gmail with pop3), the header is the same as it is in gmail... antispamcloud header is missing. So probably that it's the host provider doing exactly what you said.. he doesn't need to pass through antispamcloud because it's sending to itself. I'll try to contact them and fix this issue. In the meantime, I'll accept this answer since it's most likely what's going on!